# How to make some columns of GridLayout grow in SWT?

Tags: java, layout, swt

How to make some columns of `GridLayout` grow in `SWT`?

I put 3 controls into grid layout and found they are not grow with window, despite the fact I set `FILL` style.

[image]

The code:

```
public class GridLayout01 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GridLayout gridLayout;

        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);

        gridLayout = new GridLayout(3, false);
        shell.setLayout(gridLayout);

        {

            Label promptLabel = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
            promptLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.TOP, false, false));
            promptLabel.setText("PROMPT:");

            Text commandLineText = new Text(shell, SWT.SINGLE);
            commandLineText.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false));

            Button commandLineButton = new Button( shell, SWT.PUSH);
            commandLineButton.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.TOP, false, false));
            commandLineButton.setText("Say");

        }


        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether you want it to grow vertically or horizontally, you need to set the `GridData` as follows:

- Horizontal fill: `new GridData(SWT.FILL, ?, true, ?)`
- Vertical fill: `new GridData(?, SWT.FILL, ?, true)`

Here is the Javadoc:

```
GridData(int horizontalAlignment,
         int verticalAlignment,
         boolean grabExcessHorizontalSpace,
         boolean grabExcessVerticalSpace)
```

- `horizontalAlignment` - how control will be positioned horizontally within a cell, one of: `SWT.BEGINNING` (or `SWT.LEFT`), `SWT.CENTER`, `SWT.END` (or `SWT.RIGHT`), or `SWT.FILL`
- `verticalAlignment` - how control will be positioned vertically within a cell, one of: `SWT.BEGINNING` (or `SWT.TOP`), `SWT.CENTER`, `SWT.END` (or `SWT.BOTTOM`), or `SWT.FILL`
- `grabExcessHorizontalSpace` - whether cell will be made wide enough to fit the remaining horizontal space
- `grabExcessVerticalSpace` - whether cell will be made high enough to fit the remaining vertical space

---

Also make sure that the parent  takes up all the space you want the children to occupy.